# Docker build image for php apache

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a docker image from ubuntu where I need ti install laravel. For that I am trying to run.

I have a docker file where I am using this code:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y\
    && apt-get install apache2\
    && apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-common php-mbstring php-xmlrpc php-soap php-gd php-xml php-mysql php-cli php-mcrypt php-zip\
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |  php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 80 443
```

When I am running docker-coompose up I am getting error:

```
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y    && apt-get install apache2    && apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-common php-mbstring php-xmlrpc php-soap php-gd php-xml php-mysql php-cli php-mcrypt php-zip    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |  php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My docker-compose file is :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: .......
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8090
  web:
    build: .
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:7000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

What should I do if I need to create a docker image for my laravel application. I have a laravel application and I need to run it through docker.

Comment: Why not use a php-apache base image from here https://hub.docker.com/_/php/?

Comment: Including more of the error message before the "this command failed" line would be really helpful.

Comment: I am getting this error when using this dockerfile. If you have any suggestion to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose#step-1-%E2%80%94-downloading-laravel-and-installing-dependencies to accomplish exactly this.

If you just need the end result check out my github repo: https://github.com/RyanFletcher86/LaravelDocker

I've managed to distill it down to 2 commands to get everything up and running.